# Send a message instead of using the console to state the error

Tags: discord.js

```
             client.on("message", async message => {
                const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g) //arguments
                const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); //command
            
                if (message.content.indexOf(PREFIX) !== 0) return;
                
                if (command == "avatar") {
            
                var user;
                user = message.mentions.users.first(); //mentioned user, if any
                if (!user) { //if no one is mentioned
                if (!args[0]) { //if the command is only "!avatar". I.e. no one is mentioned and no id is specified
                user = message.author;
                getuseravatar(user);
                } else { //if a user id IS specified (need developer mode on on discord to get it)
                var id = args[0]
                bot.users.fetch(id).then(user => {
                getuseravatar(user) //get avatar of the user, whose id is specified
                
                }).catch(error => console.log(error))
                
                }
            }
                
                } else { //if someone IS mentioned
                getuseravatar(user);
                }
                function getuseravatar(user) {
                var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM") //can specifiy color of embed here
                .setImage(user.avatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: true }))
                message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
                }
            })
        })
```

Basically, what I wanted to do is: if the bot cannot get the avatar of a user or a bot (because the argument the user specifies is not a valid ID or a pinged user), the bot will reply to them letting them know about that instead of writing the error message in the console. Is there any way I can do that? I know I have to replace `.catch(error => console.log(error))` with something else, but what should I replace? I tried multiple attempts but none of those seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.catch is a function...error is the parameter passed to it.  You're choosing to use console.log(error) as the action in the catch.  You could message instead.  You have message sending code in other places of the code...for example:

```
                getuseravatar(user) //get avatar of the user, whose id is specified
                
                }).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

can become:

```
                getuseravatar(user) //get avatar of the user, whose id is specified
                
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    message.channel.send("I can't do that now Dave, I am sorry.")
                   })
```

comment out the console.log line if you wish...